# Set text on select box with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have another (probably simple) Jquery question. I just want to display the selected value of a dropdown list using Jquery. I have saved the selected value to a database and now just need it to be displayed when the user comes back to the page. I have tried every method I can think of (and google's search results!) but it doesn't work. I must be missing something simple (again) please help! I have tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("quantity").val('2');
$("quantity").text('2');
$("quantity .ui-btn-text").text('2');

$("quantity").filter(function() {
   return $(this).text() == '2';
}).attr('selected', true);

}​
```

and here is a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zv58e/

Help! 
Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $("quantity")
```

should

```
 $("#quantity").val(2);
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zv58e/1/)***

Or

```
$('select[name="quantity"]').val(2);
```

Comment: It's better to use IDs rather than names when possible.

Answer (score 0):

For using id, you should do that by using $("#quantity") and close braces properly,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#quantity").val('2');
/*
    $("#quantity").text('2');
    $("#quantity .ui-btn-text").text('2');
    $("#quantity").filter(function() {
       return $(this).text() == '2';
    }).attr('selected', true);
*/
}​);
```